# How to preserve whitespace inside a SELECT tag in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a legacy app that we are attempting to band-aid to work in Chrome because the budget for the full rewrite isn't approved yet, and yet IE is being removed from the intranet computers. It's a gov contract.

Anyway, this app likes to put multiple column of info into a SELECT tag using fixed-width font to create a nice columnar look. In the future, we'll use js widgets. But Chrome destroys the excess whitespace that IE used to preserve meaning columns don't line up anymore.

I tried the CSS white-space: pre, but it doesn't seem to take effect on SELECT nor OPTION tags.  I tried nbsp but I just get literal nbsp, which helps nothing.  Any ideas on how I can preserve whitespace inside a select tag in chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity - If you iterate through the options AFTER THEY RENDER and do a replaceAll() on the innerHTML and reset it to replace the blanks with non-breaking spaces, that appears to work.  Doesn't work against the text attribute nor if I do it before render.  Not elegant, but this is a jury-rig anyway until the budget is approved to rewrite it properly.